# How to check if the date changed in android studio?

Tags: java, android, date, android-date

I would like to know if the date changed because I need to refresh a variable the next day.

```
    Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentTime);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
    date.setText(dateFormatter.format(currentTime));
```

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
localDate.isBefore( LocalDate.now() )
```

## `java.time.LocalDate`

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes. Here you want [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class.

Get [today's date](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#now()) using the JVM’s current default time zone.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now() ;
```

Later, grab the date again, and [compare](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#isBefore(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate)).

```
boolean newDate = localDate.isBefore( LocalDate.now() ) ;
```

Or, if you think there is a possibility of the clock being messed up, [check for inequality](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#isEqual(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate)).

```
boolean dateDiffers = ! localDate.isEqual( LocalDate.now() ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with SharedPreferences- follow my code

```
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private String sharedPref = "MY_PREF";
    String REFRESH_DAILY;
    
        REFRESH_DAILY = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
         
        //check for first time 
        boolean today_Checkin = mPrefs.getBoolean(REFRESH_DAILY, false);
        if (!today_Checkin  ) {
            //new day is here
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "already done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
                
        //when you have done for today      
        editor = mPrefs.edit(); 
        editor.putBoolean(REFRESH_DAILY, true);
        editor.apply();
```